# Autofill form from Database

Tags: javascript, forms

Hi i want following thing on my java script enabled form. Whenever i select a Song on my song field album name should be auto filled from database.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I think ajax will be a better choice for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you will need two things

1) On server side, create a "GET" method which will take "Song Name" (go for Song ID) as input and will return you the "Album Name".

2) Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) make an ajax call to this GET function

```
$.ajax({
    url: url, //Your GET URL
    beforeSend: function (data) {  
        //Show some busy indicator (optional)
    },
    data: inputs + '&time=' + new Date(), //Keep this "time" parameter, makes your call unique everytime
    success: function (data) {
        //Success
    },
    error: function (data) { 
        //Show error (optional)
    }
});
```

As you don't have any "Submit" button, wire up key down event on your song name text box and on every key down, make a GET request, and on Success show album title in the respective text box.

[AAP Coding](http://learningsfromdotnet.blogspot.com/)